# I can't use the available fonts in pygame

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

I'm trying to use fonts that came with the pygame ( fonts from `pygame.font.get_fonts()` )
for example, trying to use the font 'comicsansms' (which is in the available fonts in pygame):

```
font = pygame.font.Font('comicsansms', size)
```

I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'comicsansms'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pygame.font.SysFont`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont) instead of [`pygame.font.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font):

```py
font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', size)
```

Or use [`pygame.font.match_font()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) to find the path to a specific font file:

```py
comicsansms_file = pygame.font.match_font('comicsansms')
font = pygame.font.Font(comicsansms_file, size)
```